# How to get python array without using if-else statements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I am trying to create a mask to compare two arrays A2 and A5 that have the same size and number of elements.
My professor wants the following: 
 If the element in A1's first column is positive, show elements in A2 at the same row as that element ****(Using mask)*** 
How can I accomplish this without using an if/else statement.

```
isPositiveMask = (A5[:1,0:1]>1) 
isPositiveMask

if isPositiveMask:
  print(A2[:1,0,1])
else:
    print("A1 first element in first column not positive")
```

This is what A2 and A5 look like. They hold the same exact values, size (5x4).

```
array([[-10,  -9,  -8,  -7],
       [ -6,  -5,  -4,  -3],
       [ -2,  -1,   0,   1],
       [  2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  6,   7,   8,   9]])
```

Comment: You should be able to edit your own post, instead of using a comment.

Comment: A1? A5? Is there some confusion going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is:

`print(A2[A5[:,0] > 0])`